# How to get items in a ListView and display in a ComboBox?

Tags: .net, vb.net, listview, combobox

I have created two forms:

1. Form1 - This form contains ListView1 which has staff information such as Name.
2. Form2 - This form contains ComboBox1

Now what I'm trying to accomplish is to get the Staff Names from ListView1 in Form1 and display those inside ComboBox1 in Form2. For practice purposes, I have added an item onto ListView1 through the ListViewItem Collection Editor on Visual Studio to try and figure out how to get that dummy info displayed in ComboBox1. So far, I have tried these lines of code:

```
ComboBox1.Items.Add(frmListStaffVehicleEntry.ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(1).Text)

ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = frmListStaffVehicleEntry.ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).Index
```

Answer (score 0):

I Not Sure That Whether You Want To Load All The Data In ListView1 To ComboBox1 or
You Want To Get The Data Selected At ComboBox1.
Can You Make It Clear.So That I Can Help You...

Comment: I want to load the items of the Listview1 to ComboBox1. From my understanding, ListView1 will only contain up to 10-12 items so displaying all of the items in ComboBox1 is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy all items from your listbox in form 1 to the combobox in form2 you can try:(use your names of the controls)

```
    For Each jt As String In ListBox3.Items
        Form2.ComboBox1.Items.Add(jt)
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Ive tried the code but it does not display any of my ListView items: 

`        For Each jt As String In frmListEntry.ListView1.Items
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(jt)
        Next`

Comment: You need to addess the combobox within thew form. Check my code again. Also put option strikt on.

Answer (score 0):

Just Add The Following Code On To Your **Form2_Load** Event

```
   For i As Integer = 0 To frmListStaffVehicleEntry.ListView1.Items.Count

            ComboBox1.Items.Add(frmListStaffVehicleEntry.ListView1.Items.Item(i))
        Next
```